Deploying two applications on wildfly, and getting them to communicate
I am trying to deploy two applications on wildfly version 32.0.1. One application talks to the other application. However, every time I do this, I only see the wildfly homepage when accessing my one application(because this one has a UI). I just wanted to deploy two applications that run on different ports and can communicate with one another
I have configured my standalone.xml to use virtual hosts, and have associated ports to my two virtual hosts. But still unable to get this through. I expected that I can access my one application and use it to talk to the other application. However, I just got a wildfly home page message.
Please see below my standalone.xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:14.0" statistics-enabled="true">
        <byte-buffer-pool name="default" buffer-size="1024" max-pool-size="1024"/>
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" buffer-pool="default" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <http-listener name="xsupport-http" socket-binding="http2" buffer-pool="default" enable-http2="true"/>
            <http-listener name="connex-http" socket-binding="http3" buffer-pool="default" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" buffer-pool="default" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
            <host name="xsupport-web" alias="xsupport.com" default-web-module="xsupport-tool-1.0.0.war"/>
            <host name="connex" alias="connex-api.com" default-web-module="connex-1.0.0.war"/>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/18"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.webservices.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:5.0"/>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="connex-http" interface="public" port="8888"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http2" port="${jboss.http.port:8889}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http3" port="${jboss.http.port:8888}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="tenant-http" interface="public" port="8887" fixed-port="false"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="${jboss.mail.server.host:localhost}" port="${jboss.mail.server.port:25}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>

And here is my application properties for my two application respectively
#App A
server.port=8889
spring.config.import=classpath:api-endpoints.properties
server.servlet.session.timeout=450m
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#App B
server.port=8888
spring.config.import=classpath:query-config.properties
apiPrefix=/api
web.endpoint=http://localhost:8887/
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

I have even set up my etc/hosts to point to my virtual server but still no luck

(1) use default settings , install app1.war , app2.war on wildfly (2) default webpath: http://localhost:8080/app1  and   http://localhost:8080/app2 (3) app2 , add apiPrefix, http://localhost:8080/app2/api (4) Confirm whether you are installing and deploying war or spring boot application?

I am deploying a springboot application, and building it as a war

Are you saying that you package the SpringBoot Application as a war, and then deploy the war to wildfly? For your SpringBoot Application war, you can also rename them app1.war, app2.war and then deploy to wildfly.
